# replacing inner text in a xml file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

i found this expression,

```
^[<conf-start a-z0-9- =""/><month></month>]+
```

which matches the source string

```
<conf-start iso-8601-date="2011-03-04"><day>04</day><month>March</month><year>2011</year></conf-start>
```

but i am unable to replace the month from March to 03 for eg March should replace with 03

i tried the following code,

```
    Dim mydir As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim filePath As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim directory1 As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)
    Dim split As String() = filePath.Split("\")
    Dim parentFolder As String = split(split.Length - 2)

    Dim outputLines As New List(Of String)()
    Dim stringToMatch As String = "^[<conf-start a-z0-9- =""/><month>March</month>]+"
    Dim replacementString As String = "^[<conf-start a-z0-9- =""/><month>03</month>]+"

    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TextBox1.Text & "\" & parentFolder & ".xml")
        Dim matchFound As Boolean
        matchFound = line.Contains(stringToMatch)

        If matchFound Then
            ' Replace line with string
            outputLines.Add(replacementString)
        Else
            outputLines.Add(line)
        End If
    Next
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(TextBox1.Text & "\" & parentFolder & ".xml", outputLines.ToArray(), Encoding.UTF8)
```

but i am unable to find changes in my xml file.
so anyone please help me with this.
still stuck with this problem.

Comment: Do **not** use Regex and String functions for manipulating an XML file.  Use an XML API (like LINQ-to-XML), as it is much faster, much easier to read and most importantly, **designed** for manipulating XML.

Comment: can u please give me some examples regarding it or edit my code and post me back please...

Comment: Are you trying to replace only March with 3, or any month with the corresponding number?  Is it only for certain conf-start tags? Can you post a more complete example of the XML file you're parsing? (Edit your question to post it, don't post it in the comments).

Comment: Yes it is for certain conf-start tags and i need to replace the presented month in the month tag with its respected number

Comment: <conf-start iso-8601-date="2011-03-11"><day>11</day>      <month>March</month><year>2011</year></conf-start>
<conf-end iso-8601-date="2011-03-13"><day>13</day><month>March</month><year>2011</year></conf-end>

Comment: What is the criteria for replacement?  I.e., what determines whether a certain conf-start tag has the replacement or not?

Comment: the above examples are the two lines of an xml document and i also need to do the same for <conf-end> month tag

Comment: if the month tag in conf-start consist of month name then it has to be replaced by the month number

Comment: in any case the month name should be replaced with month number

Comment: but is it possible to use to use XML API for an xml document containing errors..

Comment: What do you mean by errors?  As long as the XML is well-formed and valid then you can use an API to fix any data errors.  Did you try the updated example Dominic posted for you?

Comment: yaa i tried it bt it is showing errors such as xlink is an undeclared prefix i.e it is giving errors of the xml file which i want to read

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entirety of your XML - it sounds like you have a namespace issue in the XML, but it's impossible to give any definitive answer without seeing the XML you're trying to parse.

Comment: its an 300+ line xml file

Comment: Then post a representative sample so we can see the format of the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb387098%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [XML literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx) instead.

**Example:**

```
' Load the file '
Dim yourXml = XDocument.Load("your_path_to_the_file.xml").Root

' Change each monthname to the number of the month
For Each elem in yourXml ...<conf-start>.<month>
    elem.value = DateTime.ParseExact(elem.value, "MMMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month
Next

' save file
yourXml.Save("your_path_to_the_file.xml")
```

Comment: 2011-03-04 this expression will keep on changing per files so will

Comment: so is there a possible way to do so and the answer you have given may be correct but i have to select the folder path and enter it in textbox and on the click of a button the changes will be done automatically will u help me with this please

Comment: iso-8601-date will keep on changing eg 2011-03-04 this in one file on the other file it may be 2011-05-06

Comment: How is this related to the problem/your question?

Comment: as u can see in your above code u have entered the given iso-date that i have mentioned but i want an expression that can catch the iso-date automatically and make the changes accordingly.

Comment: ya that is what i wanna change but as u can see in my question i have also mentioned an expression for the iso-date so with the help of that expression i need to match the format in the xml file and do the changes in month tag only.

Comment: So basically your requirement is: "Change the text value of each `<Month>` element from `March` to `3` if the parent element is a `<conf-start>` with an attribute `iso-8601-date`" instead of simply "Change the text value of each `<Month>` element from `March` to `3`"?

Comment: it is showing error near xml that it is a namespace and cannot be used as an expression plz help me i am new at this.

Comment: if i want to read xml file from a folder and then execute the query that u have mentioned and make changes in that particular xml file how will it be done

Comment: its clear now but it is showing me an error 'xlink' is an undeclared prefix

Comment: Dim mydir As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim filePath As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim directory1 As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)
        Dim split As String() = filePath.Split("\")
        Dim parentFolder As String = split(split.Length - 2)

        Dim yourXml = XDocument.Load(TextBox1.Text, parentFolder & ".xml").Root

Comment: this is my path as u can see it is now showing me conversion from string to type integer is not valid

Comment: is it possible to find the expression using linq-to-xml in a xml document that consist of multiple errors using your code described above